# how can I apply a CSS stylesheet to all page views in my Firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet

I would like to apply a CSS stylesheet to all page views in a Firefox browser using a menu option and be able to toggle this when required. (The functionality I want exists in IE:   Tools | Internet Options | Accessibility | Format Documents Using my Stylesheet (although I think this may affect pages outside of simply IE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108), you can define global styles in firefox and ability to switch it on and off fast from Firefox.

[Usage page](http://userstyles.org/help/coding).

[Global styles](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/global/all/popularity/desc/1), you can see code and how it is done.

Comment: I have used Stylish and it is nice. I forgot its name. :-)

Comment: Stylish appears to be spyware. It sends your browsing history along with a unique identifier to a marketing company.

Comment: I tried Stylish and then saw a recommendation for [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us).  I like Stylus much better.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the file `userContent.css` lying within the directory named `chrome` in your Mozilla Firefox profiles directory. There is also an example file named `userContent-example.css`.

Comment: Have a look inside: `%AppData%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`.

Comment: is there a "menu option and be able to toggle this when required" (from the question) ?

Comment: @Andrija: I do not think there is a menu option.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi The path would be `%AppData%\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`

Answer (score 0):

There is another Firefox addon called [Platypus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/737) which which adds a toolbar for editing site styles. It does require you to install [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).

I just installed Stylish and my first impression is that is nicer than Platypus, especially when it comes to sharing your styles with others. But I'll reverse my judgment as to which I think is better when I have more time to compare them.   :)